# setInterval keeps on running even after the whole script is removed from the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, google-chrome-devtools, setinterval

I made a custom function to replicate setInterval function.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script id='scpt_a'>
            //custom setInterval function

     function interval(func,ti){

      try{
         func.call(null);
         }
       catch(err){
          throw new Error(err.toString());
         }
       setTimeout(()=>{interval(func,ti); },ti);
         }

       //custom setinterval function end

      $('#start).click(()=>{
          $('body').append("<script id='scpt_b'>interval(()=> 
          {console.log('hello');},10000);</script>");
       });

      $('#stop).click(()=>{
            $('#scpt_a').remove();
            $('#scpt_b').remove();
       });


       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id='start'>start</button>
       <button id='stop'>stop</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

whenever I am running this code it works fine i.e when I click on **start button** it appends the code so the code executes it and keeps on printing ***hello***. Now as I press the **stop button** it **removes** the **appended script** as well as **initial(non-appended) script**. So since the script is not there so it should stop executing but it's not happening.

I used **chrome dev tools** where I saw that after clicking the **stop button** **there was no script** (**after appending it was there**) in the HTML document but still ***hello*** was printing on the console.

please help me figure out why is so happening and how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

When you add some script to your page, it is parse by the browser. When you later remove the script tag, it does not matter, the script was already parse, and processed and it's in the browser memory. So your `interval` function will continue to run, despite the fact that your remove the script tag from the page.

Here is the illustration of this fact. I added reference to the jQuery, see the first alert, than I remove it, and after that I remove the jQuery script tag, and you can see that I can still use jQuery `$` function:

```html
<script id="s1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
 alert($);
  $("#s1").remove();
  alert($);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in xxxmatko's answer, removing a script element from the DOM does not stop it from running, assuming it has already been parsed.

You need to come up with another solution to cancel the execution of your interval. The perhaps easiest way is to use the standard `setInterval` function instead. This could be done as follows:

```
// Start the interval:
let intervalID = setInterval(function() { /* your code */}, 10000);

// Stop the interval:
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

However, if you insist on a custom interval function such as the one in your example, you could implement some functionality that lets you cancel the interval at a later point, in a similar manner. For instance, you can check for a condition in the interval function:

```
function interval(func,ti){
  /* your code */
  if ( /* some condition */ )
    setTimeout(()=>{interval(func,ti); },ti);
}
```

And when `$('#start')` or `$('#stop')` are clicked, this condition is set to true or false, respectively.

Moreover, both of these solutions avoid another issue you have in your code: If the user clicks on `$('#start')` twice, you will end up with two script elements (with the same ID!) in the DOM.